# Adding Values to Header Drupal 7 + .htaccess

Tags: 7

Well, I'm new to Drupal, I was wondering if I can add values to header?

**Note: this is the code for my mysite.com**

I got this piece of code in mysite.com

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    echo $_GET['code'];
    }

?>
```

So for example,

**Drupal URL:**

*mysite.com/U2pVnWK*

If I run that URL, it redirects me to **PAGE 404**

So I tried this, **URL:**

*mysite.com/?code=U2pVnWK*

Which it eventually works.

So I tried using RewriteRule thing in .htaccess and added this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?code=$1
```

Even change it into

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ ?code=$1
```

Also

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ http://www.mysite.com/?code=$1
```

**None** of it works.

Plus **I don't know where to put that piece of code in existing .htaccess that Drupal made it.**

So to simplify, what I want is:

If I access ***mysite.com/U2pVnWK*** I would be able to **retrieve and echo**  *U2pVnWK* instead of redirecting to PAGE 404 PAGE

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something you can try with Drupal itself.

[hook_url_inbound_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7)

> Alters inbound URL requests.

The idea is to [drupal_lookup_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_lookup_path/7) and if nothing found you can do whatever with `$path` variable in  [hook_url_inbound_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7)